# X-Axis pose flip does not work properly in part of armature

Tags: armature, pose-mode

I have a problem because one arm in my human armature doesn't want to flip correctly:

[image]

as you can see left arm position is invalid, what can cause that issue?

model: https://www.dropbox.com/s/7cez1pub1z78468/hero_test.blend?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, it seem a problem with roll of your UpperArm_L bone, it isn't mirror of its counterpart.

1. Go to edit mode of your armature.
2. Select the UpperArm_L Bone.
3. Click the Bone tab.
4. set the Roll from -162.7d to 39.86d.
5. This would offset all child bones, do the above changes to roll for Forearm_L(35.73d), then WristIK_L(49.01d), then Wrist_L(50.17d) copy the negative of Right side roll. (Do it in said order)
6. All set to go.

Comment: But, my hand now is weird rotated, and if I correct that to don't have to do it in every animation, flip will not work. What I can do to set correct rotation and have valid x-flip?

Comment: can you show a screenshot, it seem to work fine in my case?

Comment: The roll value in my bone was set to -49.01d, am I watching something else? WristIK_R>Bone>Roll

Comment: Ok, I see UpperArm_R roll to be -39.86d, but UpperArm_L is -162.7d, change that to "39.86d" also change the "Forearm_L, then WristIK_L, then Wrist_L" roll in that order ... it works now (sorry didn't see multiple IK on hand), Ill change the answer to reflect the change. Can i know the idea behind why you did rig the character this way? I have seen either no IK on hand or only one IK on forearm, not on both forearm and upper arm.

Comment: Sorry but I don't understand you in part of your comment where are you talking about my weird IK setup. I am new to IK and this setup I was making from a course, what can I improve here?

Comment: usually I prefer no IK on hand, easy to work, but I have seen some with IK set on forearm only, not at all on upper arm. Can you point me to the tutorial you are following, could help me learn new stuff

Comment: my armature I was making according to this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4yiC6pEQMAw